# Accessing the Files in the Resource Folder .Net 3.5

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

I am trying to create a temporary file then change the temporary file to a .dotx that I have embedded into my C# program in Visual Studio.  The code that I have below does not work correctly, the third line of Code where I try to reference my File in the Namespace.Properties.Resources.Myfile returns a build error saying there is no definition for the call.

Does anyone know of a better way to access this file in the folder I need.

```
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();  // create a temp file
fileName = Path.ChangeExtension(fileName,"dotx");    //change the ext to dotx

File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, NameSpace.Properties.Resources.MyFile.dotx);
//This line of code returns the build error
```

Comment: Unfortunately that edit did not fix the build error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
public void WriteResourceToFile(string resourceName, string fileName)
{
    using(var resource = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
    {
        using(var file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            resource.CopyTo(file);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: the resource name MyFile.dotx, the code does not accept the resourceName that I have given it

Comment: Are you sure you have marked your file as an embedded resource?

Comment: That might be the problem cause there are two other files in the folder and they can be accessed.  How do mark it as an embedded resource?  I only added as an item to the Resource folder.

Comment: @tennis779 In solution explorer select the file, for it's properties under advanced make sure Build Action is set to embedded resource.

Comment: Okay Thanks it compiles now, THANK YOU very much

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use File.WriteAllBytes you have to open your existed file, read it to byte array and than pass that array into File.WriteAllBytes

```
using (var filestream = File.Open(YOUR_EXISTED_PATH, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[filestream.Length];
                    filestream.Read(buffer, 0, (int) filestream.Length);
                    File.WriteAllBytes(YOUR_NEW_PATH, buffer);
                }
```

But I like previous solution more.